# Phantom Queries in PyMSQL + SQLAlchemy on Lambda

Tags: python, mysql, lambda, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm trying to debug an issue that one of our developers recently revealed.
We're using AWS Lambda functions to periodically query our MySQL DB.
These functions are written in Python 3.7, with a Lambda layer added to support using PyMSQL, SQLAlchemy, and Pandas.
The (summarized and redacted) code looks like this:

```
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

mysql_connector = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://' + oltp_username + ':' + oltp_password + '@' + host + '/' + db_name)
query = """
        SELECT sum(field) + """
        FROM schema.table;
        """
df = pd.read_sql(query, mysql_connector)
```

The works just fine, and returns the expected results, however there is a strange side-effect. Our query-logging software indicates that two queries are being received from this function: the expected query in its proper format, along with a mysterious query that looks like this:

```
DESCRIBE `
        SELECT sum(field)
        FROM schema.table;
        `
```

In MySQL this is obviously a malformed query, since DESCRIBE operates on tables. Our query logging software indicates that this error appears for every single query that is run from this Lambda function.

Does anybody know where these phantom queries might be coming from? I presume it's some option in either PyMYSQL or SQLAlchemy, but I can't find anything in the documentation. Also, why are these being sent? Including a DESCRIBE makes no sense. I suspect it's just sending the raw query string to the DESCRIBE function, due to an expression like `DATE_FORMAT(datefield,"%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%i:00")` appearing with the consecutive %, instead of being properly escaped, as it is in the correct query.

Comment: I can reproduce this using SQLAlchemy 1.3, only if the query is executed by Pandas.  At a guess, Pandas wants to know about the resultset's "table structure" and this triggers erroneous code in SQLA.  The extra query doesn't happen in 1.4, or if Pandas is not involved in 1.3.

Comment: `read_sql` tries to support both tables and queries. When you pass it a string, it cannot know if it is a table name or a query, so maybe it first assumes a table (I'm guessing here). You could instead use `pandas.read_sql_query` explicitly.

Comment: The calls go from [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/eccfe9097ecf5d0d5fd5437290e956757d27933e/pandas/io/sql.py#L612) to [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/eccfe9097ecf5d0d5fd5437290e956757d27933e/pandas/io/sql.py#L1779) in Pandas to [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/ee17cbad9ed4adbc1a6a1b6273ad1ded66e25d99/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py#L2599) in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @snakecharmerb thank you! Upgrading worked just fine. It's an interesting bug, and I'm glad it's fixed in the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

snakecharmerb and Ilja Everilä provided a few answers in the comments, all of which work. Thanks!

1. Upgrade SQLAlchemy to version 1.4
2. Don't use pandas to execute the SQL.
3. Use pandas read_sql_query function instead of read_sql.